# Hot-swap new .class,.properties file in tomcat instance without restarting it

Tags: java, tomcat

I have some(say 5) tomcat instances running behind a load-balancer. Now the situation is that I need to add a new tomcat instance(6th) and with some of the files(.java,.properties files) modified from the original war file. Now I am deploying this new modified war file only to new tomcat instance. Is it possible any how that the changed files in new war files be propagated in other tomcats that were running before without actually stopping-deploying-starting any of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you version the war name, tomcat 7 can hot deploy the new version of the war and gracefully move new sessions to the new war while leaving existing sessions on the previous version.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html